# Audio problem after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04

I have four amateur radio related windows programs that I run with Crossover/Wine - Winlink Express, VARA-HF, VARA-FM, and Soundmodem.  The last three are software modems used by Winlink Express, which also has it's own internal software modem called ARDOP.  All of these use an external soundcard interface called a SignaLink.  Each modem is separately configured to select the soundcard being used.

After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, Winlink Express using ARDOP still works just fine, but the other three modems have the following problem:
     The output (transmit side) works fine.
     The input (receive side) doesn't.  Even though the indicator on the sound settings page shows the SignaLink as the selected device, and sound levels are being received from it, within the apps themselves no sound is being received from the SignaLink.  The soundcard config option within the app is selected as PulseAudio (it's the only option that shows up).  Here's what's really weird.  If I have the computer's internal microphone turned on, those three modems receive audio from the internal microphone EVEN IF THE SIGNALINK IS THE SELECTED DEVICE on the ubuntu sound settings page.  If I turn off the internal microphone, the app receives nothing.

So, it seems like some virtual wires are getting crossed somewhere for these three modems.  Under Ubuntu 19.10, all four modems were working fine.

I've read quite a few posts here concerning other sound problems since the upgrade came out, although nothing quite like this.  One answer indicated a problem with the new linux kernel in ubuntu 20.04.  Could my problem be caused by that?  If so, why does the ARDOP modem still work and the other three don't?  Is a fix being worked on?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Found a work-around.  Not listed this as answered because this is still a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Work around:  Installed pavucontrol.  This program showed that the internal microphone was selected even when the ubuntu settings screen showed the right one.  So I changed the device in pavucontrol and VIOLA!   Everything works.